# ANDROID client server not working

Tags: java, android

I created a program to read a speech ,transfer it to text and then send it over WiFi to the server.

The speech recognition works perfectly.But the data is not received at the server.However the client server worked fine when used separate from speech recognition .

heres my code  ..

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    protected static final int RESULT_SPEECH = 1;

    private ImageButton btnSpeak;
    private TextView txtText;
    public ArrayList<String> text;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        txtText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtText);

        btnSpeak = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnSpeak);

        btnSpeak.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {



                Intent intent = new Intent(
                        RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);

                intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, "en-US");

                try {
                    startActivityForResult(intent, RESULT_SPEECH);
                    txtText.setText("");
                } catch (ActivityNotFoundException a) {
                    Toast t = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Ops! Your device doesn't support Speech to Text",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    t.show();
                }
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        switch (requestCode) {
        case RESULT_SPEECH: {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {

                text = data
                        .getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);

                //txtText.setText(text.get(0));
                //
                 //Log.d("inputString", text.get(0));
                 new Thread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {

                            try{
                                txtText.setText("excepion in");
                                URL url = new URL("http://192.168.137.1:8080/SpeeCom/DoubleMeServlet");
                                //URL url = new URL("http://10.0.2.2:8080/server/DoubleMeServlet");
                                URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();

                                //String inputString = inputValue.getText().toString();
                                //inputString = URLEncoder.encode(inputString, "UTF-8");



                                connection.setDoOutput(true);
                                OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream());
                                out.write(text.get(0));
                                out.close();





                                }catch(Exception e)
                                {
                                    txtText.setText("excepion" + e);
                                }

                        }
                      }).start();




                //



            }
            break;
        }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Umm.. the formatting.. it hurts!

Comment: Please do not use line number in your code here.

Comment: Your question needs massive editing. Fix code formatting and also we don't know anything about your server or API.

Comment: How are we supposed to read this code?

Comment: Guys .is it readable now ?

Comment: What is "client server"?

Comment: Simply i send a message from android(Client)  to pc(server) url : http://192.168.137.1:8080/SpeeCom/DoubleMeServlet

Answer (score 0):

Try to come closer to the problem by check values to send:

```
    try{
        txtText.setText("excepion in");
        URL url = new URL("http://192.168.137.1:8080/SpeeCom/DoubleMeServlet");
        //URL url = new URL("http://10.0.2.2:8080/server/DoubleMeServlet");
        URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();

        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream());

        String mess = "start--" + text.get(0);
        Log.d(mess);
        out.write(mess);

    }catch(Exception e){
        txtText.setText("excepion" + e);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }finally{
        out.close();
    }
```

what is the output?